# Record grouping with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb, for an application, I have schema,

```
{
  date: "date",
  data:"encrypted data",
  sender:"sender",
  receiver:"receiver"
}
```

and I am expecting group of records clubbed in a object, with group by sender/receiver name which is not equal to a specific value.
for ex.

```
{
  date: "date",
  data:"encrypted data",
  sender:"xyz",
  receiver:"abc"
},
{
  date: "date",
  data:"encrypted data",
  sender:"abc",
  receiver:"xyz"
},
{
  date: "date",
  data:"encrypted data",
  sender:"pqr",
  receiver:"abc"
},
{
  date: "date",
  data:"encrypted data",
  sender:"abc",
  receiver:"pqr"
},
{
  date: "date",
  data:"encrypted data",
  sender:"pqr",
  receiver:"xyz"
},
{
  date: "date",
  data:"encrypted data",
  sender:"xyz",
  receiver:"pqr"
}
```

and when I uses find(abc) with some group function, I need the data in bellow format.

```
{
xyz:[
    {
      date: "date",
      data:"encrypted data",
      sender:"xyz",
      receiver:"abc"
    },
    {
      date: "date",
      data:"encrypted data",
      sender:"abc",
      receiver:"xyz"
    }
    ],
pqr:[
    {
      date: "date",
      data:"encrypted data",
      sender:"pqr",
      receiver:"abc"
    },
    {
      date: "date",
      data:"encrypted data",
      sender:"abc",
      receiver:"pqr"
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I use $group or any other feature of mongodb which gives result in given format?

Comment: Getting it in that format out of aggregation would be impossible except when you know every single name and put all of them into your $project statement, and that would scale horribly. But it would be possible to get an array of objects with one object for each user. You could then transform it into a key/value table on your application layer.

Comment: @Philipp, Nothing is impossible in this world, if this is not possible with a way, it can be possible with another way.  And I am finding any method to solve this problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to achieve the desired result. The aggregation pipeline would simply have the initial [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage which reshapes each document in the stream, such as by removing just the mongodb's `_id` field since you don't require it in the output.

The next pipeline stage would be the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator step which groups input documents from the previous [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage by the specified identifier `receiver` key and applies the accumulator expression [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/#grp._S_addToSet) to each group which simply adds the system variable [**`$$ROOT`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) to an array `data`.

Once you get the aggregation pipeline, you would need to iterate over the aggregation result using its cursor's [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) method to create the final result object:

```
var result = {};
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "date": 1,
            "data": 1,
            "sender": 1,
            "receiver": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$receiver",
            "data": {
                "$addToSet": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
]).forEach(function (doc){
        result[doc._id] = doc.data
});
printjson(result);
```

**Output**:

```
{
        "pqr" : [
                {
                        "date" : "date",
                        "data" : "encrypted data",
                        "sender" : "xyz",
                        "receiver" : "pqr"
                },
                {
                        "date" : "date",
                        "data" : "encrypted data",
                        "sender" : "abc",
                        "receiver" : "pqr"
                }
        ],
        "xyz" : [
                {
                        "date" : "date",
                        "data" : "encrypted data",
                        "sender" : "pqr",
                        "receiver" : "xyz"
                },
                {
                        "date" : "date",
                        "data" : "encrypted data",
                        "sender" : "abc",
                        "receiver" : "xyz"
                }
        ],
        "abc" : [
                {
                        "date" : "date",
                        "data" : "encrypted data",
                        "sender" : "pqr",
                        "receiver" : "abc"
                },
                {
                        "date" : "date",
                        "data" : "encrypted data",
                        "sender" : "xyz",
                        "receiver" : "abc"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: +1 for clubbing data in object with name, But it is not grouping if sender and receiver are swapped. its creating separate group for those